# How can I use APIs to transmit speech data of a voice call in a iOS application?

Tags: ios, api

I would like to transimt speech data of a voice call in a iOS application I'm writing. This is intended for personal use, not the App Store,  to accomplish this, I know I have to know iPhone functions about voice interface and I also know the interface functions are not open. How I can get iOS API about voice interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need pjsip library:
http://www.pjsip.org/